# Getting certain SharedPreference file based on variable

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

I'm making a companion app for a table-top RPG. Basically it just tracks characters and their development. At the moment, I feel like my main package is quite cluttered due to each character having its own SharedPreferences file. I got around the code I don't know by just having 6 preset character slots that can be used as the user desires. This required me to duplicate the package 5 times. It looks like this:

[image: Package Structure]

Within each class I get the respective Pref file as follows:

```
SharedPreferences pref;
pref = getSharedPreferences("Character1", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
~~~~~~~~~~~OR~~~~~~~~~~~
pref = getSharedPreferences("Character2", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
etc.
```

When necessary, I'll get all characters' pref files like so:

```
char1pref = getSharedPreferences("Character1", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
char2pref = getSharedPreferences("Character2", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
char3pref = getSharedPreferences("Character3", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
char4pref = getSharedPreferences("Character4", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
char5pref = getSharedPreferences("Character5", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
char6pref = getSharedPreferences("Character6", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

This is necessary in the MainActivity where I display the Characters' Names on the buttons instead of the preset of `Character 1`, `Character 2`, etc.

This hasn't been an issue until now. In the future (after I push out a massive UI update) there will be a create character button that will create these classes and the pref files upon clicking. So, my problem is that I don't know how to handle this within one class for each type; IE `ArmorStatsSP.java` would be the only class for Armor Stats and the pref file that's grabbed would depend on what character the user is currently viewing.

So, my question is: How do I grab a certain SharedPreferences file based on the current character the user is viewing; IE, if the user is viewing character 2, character2 file would be fetched for the Pref data. If they're viewing character 1, character1 file would be fetched, etc.

Within each Pref file, the keys all share the same name throughout the files; IE `name` in `Character1` is also `name` in `Character2` and so on.

I see tow possible solutions:

1.) declare different names for each Pref file like I do in MainActivity:

```
char1pref = getSharedPreferences("Character1", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
char2pref = getSharedPreferences("Character2", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
char3pref = getSharedPreferences("Character3", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
char4pref = getSharedPreferences("Character4", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
char5pref = getSharedPreferences("Character5", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
char6pref = getSharedPreferences("Character6", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

Then, set a switch for these based on `int position` (character number)

```
@Override
public void prefSelector(int position) {

    switch(position){
        case 0:
             char1pref = getSharedPreferences("Character1", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            break;
        case 1:
            char2pref = getSharedPreferences("Character2", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            break;
        case 2:
            char3pref = getSharedPreferences("Character3", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            break;
        default: 
            char4pref = getSharedPreferences("Character4", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            break; 
    }
```

2.) setup a new class `PrefSelector` and have the pref file be set based on the ID of the button pushed to get into the character; IE if `@+id/character1` was pushed, then `Character1` pref file would be fetched. If `@+id/character2` was pushed, then `Character2` pref file would be fetched, etc.

The following code is just an example. It's actually riddled with errors that I'm unsure how to fix.

```
package com.mikitz.rogsimple;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;

public class PrefSelector extends Activity{

SharedPreferences pref;

if (ID = character1) {
    pref = getSharedPreferences("Character1", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
} else if (ID = character2) {
    pref = getSharedPreferences("Character2", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
} else if (ID = character3) {
    pref = getSharedPreferences("Character3", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
} else if (ID = character4) {
    pref = getSharedPreferences("Character4", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
} else if (ID = character5) {
    pref = getSharedPreferences("Character5", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
} else if (ID = character6) {
    pref = getSharedPreferences("Character6", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
}                   
}
```

I'm not sure either of these is the most effective solution, so I came here to ask for advice from more experienced coders. Not only this, but if either of the aforementioned solutions is the ideal solution, I've also come seeking help on how to implement it.

Thanks for your time, everyone :)

Comment: Wondering why you are using shared pref? instead of that use Database to store info of any character. You have same classes in each character if I am not wrong? If yes, it is so much redundancy.

Comment: there are no classes, each character just has a list of skills and attributes that they can pick and choose to define their own class.